# problem insert data from explode array to database

Tags: php, database

I have code php. and I wont insert to database. this code wrong insert can help correction my code php

this code

```
$data = "3 003.3.003.003.006 31500.0,3 003.3.003.003.003 76500.0,4 003.3.003.003.002 72000.0,5 003.3.003.003.004 153750.0,6 003.3.003.003.005 187500.0,3 003.3.003.003.001 46500.0,";


$exone = explode(",",$data);
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $exone ); $i++ ) { $extwo = explode(" ",$exone[$i]);

for ( $j = 0; $j < count( $extwo); $j++ ) { echo $extwo[$j]. "<br />";


$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('$extwo[$j]','$extwo[$j]',$extwo[$j]')";
echo $sql;}}
```

Comment: Just `echo`ing your `$sql` won't do anything. Also, you're inserting the same value for qty, kode and price? What is the expected output and what do you get?

Comment: this $data $data = "3 003.3.003.003.006 31500.0,
3 003.3.003.003.003 76500.0,
4 003.3.003.003.002 72000.0,
5 003.3.003.003.004 153750.0,
6 003.3.003.003.005 187500.0,
3 003.3.003.003.001 46500.0,
";

Comment: i wont insert values for " $extwo[$j] "

Answer (score 1):

String end with comma "," so probably at last point program tries to add null. Try to erase last commas.

Comment: after comma"," enter

Comment: Try this this $data $data = "3 003.3.003.003.006 31500.0, 3 003.3.003.003.003 76500.0, 4 003.3.003.003.002 72000.0, 5 003.3.003.003.004 153750.0, 6 003.3.003.003.005 187500.0, 3 003.3.003.003.001 46500.0,-";

Comment: yes..true data.. and then data don't insert to table $sql.. help or correction my code

Comment: "INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('$extwo[$j]','$extwo[$j]','$extwo[$j]')" try this one and be carefull with quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for your second `for` loop, you can access the values after 
`explode`.

`explode()` your `$data` string by `,`, loop over the results and `explode()` each result (if it is not empty) by space:

```
<?php

$data = "3 003.3.003.003.006 31500.0,3 003.3.003.003.003 76500.0,4 003.3.003.003.002 72000.0,5 003.3.003.003.004 153750.0,6 003.3.003.003.005 187500.0,3 003.3.003.003.001 46500.0,";
$exone = explode(",", $data);

foreach ( $exone as $x ) {
    if ( !empty($x) ) {
        $extwo = explode(" ", $x);
        // var_dump($extwo);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('{$extwo[0]}','{$extwo[1]}','{$extwo[2]}');";
        echo $sql . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('3','003.3.003.003.006','31500.0');
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('3','003.3.003.003.003','76500.0');
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('4','003.3.003.003.002','72000.0');
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('5','003.3.003.003.004','153750.0');
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('6','003.3.003.003.005','187500.0');
INSERT INTO tbl_test(qty, kode, price) VALUES('3','003.3.003.003.001','46500.0');
```

If you uncomment the line `// var_dump($extwo);` you'll see that `$extwo` is an array with your desired values. You can access them using `$extwo[0]`, `$extwo[1]` ...